# android listview item no longer clickable?

Tags: android, listview

my list view items is no longer clickable after i add background xml resource to listview item xml layout , if i clicked on any item in listview the background dose not effected
where is the problem in my code and how i can fix it , i mean can i add onclick background color in `forum_box_bi.xml` resource , without losing current settings  ?

this is the listview item xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e3e4e6"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thread_bit_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
        android:background="@drawable/forum_box_bit"
        android:padding="5dip" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--  Post Aavatar + time + username  -->
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postbit_useravatar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/no_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postbit_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postbit_useravatar"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="sss"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postbit_boxmenu"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/mini_menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postbit_timestamp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#b9b9b9"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postbit_useravatar"
            android:layout_below="@+id/postbit_username"
            android:text="timestamp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

     </RelativeLayout>  
<!-- // Post User Aavatar + time + username -->




   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and this is forum_box_bit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#c4c5c6" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually You have to set a selector as background. What is "forum_box_bit", is this a selector? If not define one in Your drawables folder like this example:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

       <item 
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/default_shape"></item>
       <item
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_shape"></item>

       <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable/default_shape"></item>

    </selector>
```

You could define a background like an image or create some xml shapes for this selector.

### EDIT

For some shapes, define a shape for the pressed state and one for the unpressed state inside drawable folder:

pressed (pressed_shape.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
         <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/dark_orange_pressed"
            android:endColor="@color/light_orange_pressed"/>
       <corners 
          android:radius="5dp"/>
       <stroke 
         android:color="@color/light_gray"
         android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
```

unpressed (default_shape.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/dark_orange"
            android:endColor="@color/light_orange"/>
    <corners 
            android:radius="5dp"/>
    <stroke 
            android:color="@color/light_gray"
            android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
```

and to define colors, create a xml inside Your values folder, it has to be named as "colors.xml":

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <resources>

         <color name="dark_orange">#f6801c</color>
         <color name="light_orange">#f1a84a</color>
         <color name="light_gray">#cfcfcf</color>
         <color name="dark_orange_pressed">#b07d3b</color>
         <color name="light_orange_pressed">#d29648</color>

       </resources>
```

Comment: thank you for your lovely advice , can i define `android:drawable="@drawable/default_bg_or_shape"` as a color like #000000 or i have to use Image ! i don't get it when u said `xml shapes`